# Build info page shows 'Parameters' button\link multiple times

Tags: jenkins, parameters, build

Someone knows how to fix this?
[image]

Comment: Do you manipulate with parameter actions in the job? Probably with some groovy scripts?

Comment: Yeap, this is the reason?

Comment: I think so. Each parameter action is renderered on ui though not all links function properly. I mean we faced the same behavior and took this as unwanted but noncritical implications of our groovy hacking. I guess jenkins ui code doesnt expect more than one parameter action.

Comment: Thanks for your response!